# How to centre a button of an image

Tags: html, css

just have a simple HTML CSS question. How do I place a button over the image in the centre?

Current code:

```css
.button-link{
  text-decoration:none !important;
  color:white;
}

.button-td{
  background:#FFA06A;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center-on-narrow" role="presentation" style="display:table !important;" mc:edit="imagewithcta">
  <tr>
    <td class="button-td">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1" style="max-width:600px;" alt="photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1"><a class="button-a sans text-white" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*">
      <span class="button-link">
        READ MORE
      </span>
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, positioning container as relative and element as absolute:

```
   .button-a{
      text-decoration: none !important;
      color:white;
      position: absolute;
      top:50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }

    .button-td{
      background:#FFA06A;
      text-align:center;
      position: relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use absolute positioning within `td`.

I've added following css.

```
.button-a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```css
.button-link {
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: white;
}

.button-a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button-td {
  background: #FFA06A;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center-on-narrow" role="presentation" style="display:table !important;" mc:edit="imagewithcta">
  <tr>
    <td class="button-td">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1" style="max-width:600px;" alt="photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1">
      <a class="button-a sans text-white" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*">
        <span class="button-link">
                  READ MORE
                </span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `position` CSS property, e.g.

```
.button-td {
    position: relative;
}

.button-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

This will put the button in the center of `button-td`

Btw. I recommend You using a different tag for a button, instead of span. Try `<button>` or `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this code in which I use position property of css and it works properly.

```css
 .button-link{
    text-decoration:none !important;
    color:white;
  }

  .button-td{
    position: relative;
    background:#FFA06A;
    text-align:center;
  }
  a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 250px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest you can achieve this is by using "display: flex" to center the items horizontally and vertically then proceed by stacking the items on top of each other like so.

This method is also responsive approach on any screen width and situation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Image Centering</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #container {
        border: 1px solid black;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      img {
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
      }
      a {
        display: flex;
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1"
        style="max-width: 600px"
        alt="photo-1598257006626-48b0c252070d?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1"
      />
      <a class="button-a sans text-white" href="*|ARCHIVE3|*">
        <span class="button-link">READ MORE</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This should work like a charm.